# Java: interacting with JFrame of another (JVM) process

Tags: java, swing, automation, jvm

Say we have a Java Swing application, **swingapp**, running in one JVM. Is it possible to control **swingapp** from a Java application running in *another* JVM/process, e.g. like this:

*ControlApp.java*

```
process = startSwingAppInAnotherProcess();
JFrame frame = getSwingAppJFrame();
frame.visible(false) // hide swingapps JFrame
doAllKindsOfThingsWithJFrame(frame)..
killSwingApp(process);
```

The use case is GUI testing, where I want a generic solution that can start/stop any Swing app in an external process to isolate it from the test runner completely, but it should still be able to control the app via Swing manipulation.

If possible, concrete examples would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are platform-dependent ways to send UI events to GUI elements in the same desktop; however I would better think of some standard interprocess communication.

You can try to start your applications in a certain port range and just make them search for each sibling and communicate between them by sockets.  Or you can start a kind of parent daemon process in which every child registers itself (by sockets again), and then the parent communicates state changes to its children (something like a distributed version of Subject-Observer pattern)

Comment: socket is a bit low level though, I would probably look into using JMS.

Comment: If you think your environment requires of asynchronous communication, it is the right choice.  However, be aware that it requires a heavy infrastructure to run - maybe a JBoss server would be the lightest I know in order to put JMS to work.

Comment: You can also apply HornetQ standalone I believe, you don't need a full-blown JEE server.

Answer (score 0):

One could use somewhat "higher" level sockets - [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual) for this.

Here are [client](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:rrclient) and [server](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:rrserver) implementations:

You could start with a server to implement jframe.hide API call.

Note: if you don't like native C transport implementation, then you could just switch to
[pure java version](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) without additional changes to your code.